# Get an `SBObject` instance's real type

Tags: c#, appkit, scripting-bridge

(This question is tagged `c#` because I'll be doing this from Xamarin, but this is more of a framework question; the language shouldn't matter.)

I'm trying to interact with Music (née iTunes) using Scripting Bridge. To that end, I can get the `SBApplication` and ask it for properties; for example, `playerState` will get me whether it's currently playing, and `sources` will basically get me the entire library, hierarchically.

But that's fairly low-level, so I dug into `sdef` and `sdp` to generate some XML and a header file, in order to write some matching wrapper classes that match those described.

The part where I get stuck is basically inheritance. The `playlists` property can contain different kinds of playlists (such as `MusicPlaylist`, `MusicFolderPlaylist`, etc., all of which inherit from `MusicPlaylist`), and I'm only interested in `MusicUserPlaylist` instances.

But I'm confused how to even ask an instance its type *at all*, much less efficiently. I see that `debugDescription` answer this, for example:

```
<SBObject @0x6000008bf180: <class 'cUsP'> id 28712
of <class 'cSrc'> id 63 of application "Music" (8034)>
```

And I can see from the `sdef` that `cUsP` is what I'm looking for:

```xml
<class name="user playlist" code="cUsP"
description="custom playlists created by the user"
inherits="playlist" plural="user playlists">
    …
</class>
```

But… am I really supposed to parse `description` for this? Surely there's a nicer way? I see that the constructor always takes an `elementCode`:

```
- (instancetype) initWithElementCode:(DescType)code
properties:(nullable NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)properties data:(nullable id)data;
```

(I'm actually not a 100% on whether `DescType` is the same thing as e.g. `class 'cUsP'`?)

And yet, there doesn't appear to be a way to get that element code *back*?

TL;DR: given an `SBElementArray` that can contain various subclasses, how do I verify that an instance's dynamic scripting bridge type is a certain class?